# How should I get this specific text from str?

Tags: java

I have a lot of strings in database like this : `"\\LDDESKTOP\news\1455Bloomberg Document # 180784.txt"`. I want to get the file name after the last slash.

I do this just in a normal way :

```
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)
```

But it doesn't work because the single slash is used for change meanings. Is there a way in java just like python to tell compiler to regard it as a plain string like this , `str=r'.......'` .

Or how to change the string to `"\\\\LDDESKTOP\\news\\1455Bloomberg Document # 180784.txt"`. So I can pass it to File Object to read this file.

how should I do this? Or other ways to solve this.

Thanks.

The column named path(varchar(150)) in the news table is like this "\LDDESKTOP\news\1362Bloomberg Document # 180691.txt"

And I do a normal select on the path.

the code :

```
public List<String> getNewsFileName(String startTime,String endTime) {
    List<String> newsFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    String tableName = ConfigFile.getConfig("configuration.txt","SQLServerTable");
    String sql = "select Path from [" + tableName + "] where localtime >= '" + startTime + "' and localtime <= '" + endTime + "'";
    try {
        if(connection==null) {
            InvertedIndex.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Database connection has not been initialized");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        stmt=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()) {
            String path=rs.getString(1);
            newsFileNames.add(path);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        InvertedIndex.logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Fail to store news");
    }
    return newsFileNames;
}
```

Comment: If you System.out.println(newsFileNames); before you return, what does that give you?  It should be a List of some sort.  I'm just unable to tell the actual output based on that code alone.

Comment: just a list of string like this : "\\LDDESKTOP\news\1455Bloomberg Document # 180784.txt" , single slash instead of double.

Comment: So are you asking how to modify each string to have all double backslashes?

Comment: yeah , you can say that. If I got the double backslashes , then I can pass it to File object to read.

Comment: Or just get the file name , then I can combine the path later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the efforts you have made . Finally , I think I have found the answer.

Instead of dealing with the string in java program, I process the string using sql functions directly.

Following is what I do.

```
SELECT * substring(path,len(path)-charindex('\',reverse(path))+2,charindex('\',reverse(path)))
 FROM News
```

This really does a good job !!

Answer (score 3):

You use [Escape Sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) to specify certain special characters that also have java properties assigned to them.

In order to print a single backslash character in a string you use a set of 2 backslashes `\\`.

```
String string = new String("\\\\LDDESKTOP\\news\\1455Bloomberg Document # 180784.txt");

String str = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);

System.out.println(str);
```

This prints

```
1455Bloomberg Document # 180784.txt
```

Edit 1:

Once you have the string, you can pass it back using the same escape character.

```
String string = "\\\\LDDESKTOP\\news\\" + str;
```

This outputs the original

```
\\LDDESKTOP\news\1455Bloomberg Document # 180784.txt
```

Edit 2:

Based on what you asked, in order to transform all single backslashes into double backslashes you must use both the escape sequence and the string "replace" method.

If you have this string:

```
String string = new String("\\\\LDDESKTOP\\news\\1455Bloomberg Document # 180784.txt");
```

You need to call this code to "double" every backslash:

```
String newString = string.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

This produces the following:

```
//Note this is before we print it.  This illustrates all the escape sequences.
\\\\\\\\LDDESKTOP\\\\news\\\\1455Bloomberg Document # 180784.txt
```

The string itself will look like this:

```
\\\\LDDESKTOP\\news\\1455Bloomberg Document # 180784.txt
```

Comment: The problem is the string is get from database. I can not change it

Comment: Could you show me an example of how you are getting them from the database?  Are you reading them in from a text file or something?

Comment: just read from a column named path. It is defined as varchar(150)

Comment: I will need you to give me an example of this column and how you are reading it in.  If you scan in a string it will read a single backslash as a backslash.  Once its saved to the string you can use this: String str = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);  Just edit onto your question so I can help you further.

Comment: I have updated this answer to show you how to double the backslashes.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15107/discussion-between-mrhappyasthma-and-xuqin1019)

Answer (score 2):

this code :

```
String st = "\\LDDESKTOP\news\1455Bloomberg Document # 180784.txt";

st = st.replace("\n", "\\n");

st = st.replace("\\", "\\\\");

String str = st.substring(st.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
```

test it.
"\n" is line break.

Comment: @xuqin1019 I understand that the string from the db can't be changed.Tell us the format in which the string is stored , if the format is like what is mentioned  in ur question then getting the name of the file is simple as posted by habib or happayasthma

Comment: i think  String path=rs.getString(1); is new string object

Comment: yeah , the format of the path column is exactly varchar(150), and the path store in it is the normal path without double backslash

Comment: yeah , there is another single backslash. And the number behind always changes